# How to align RecyclerView Grid Layout Items to the left with fixed number of columns?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I have a recyclerview with grid layout in which I want to align items to the left with fixed number of columns.

Currently,the recyclerview grid layout divides the width into number of items and places them in equal margins.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_grid_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_2"
    android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin_5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_param_1" >

    <com.carwale.carwale.ui.widgets.CarwaleTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_grid_item_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/warm_grey"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_h4"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
RecyclerView recyclerGridLayout = new RecyclerView(mContext);
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
recyclerGridLayout.setHasFixedSize(true);
int spanCount = 4; // 3 columns
int rowSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(20);
int columnSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(6);
recyclerGridLayout.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, rowSpacing, columnSpacing));

recyclerGridLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerGridLayout.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, spanCount));
GridLayoutAdapter gridLayoutAdapter = new GridLayoutAdapter(mContext);
recyclerGridLayout.setAdapter(gridLayoutAdapter);
```

```
@Override
    public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item columngrid
        outRect.left = column * columnSpacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * rowSpacing)
        outRect.right = columnSpacing - (column + 1) * columnSpacing / spanCount; // rowSpacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * rowSpacing)
        if (position >= spanCount) {
            outRect.top = rowSpacing; // item top
        }
    }
```

Current Result:
[image: list of items in grid layout]

Expected Result:
[image: list of items in grid layout the result I want]

Answer (score 0):

Every time the user clicks on the Item modify the `RecyclerView` dataset array based on the order in which the user clicks and call RecyclerView `adapter.notifyDatasetchanged()`

Comment: Its not about alternating UI between selected and unselected state, i wanted to align the items left. Currently the grid view divides the width with numer of columns and assigns equal space. I want them to be left align with margin 16dp between them